# c# - How to multithreading Iterate Through a Directory Tree, in folder 1000000 files

Tags: c#, multithreading

I need to save in database file Name and Size in byte from folder and all subfolder.
In this folder lay 1 000 000 files.
And when I use example from [msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb513869.aspx) it works 4 days, that very slowly.

```
     static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string pdxPathDocFiles = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["PDX_PathDocFiles"] as string;
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(pdxPathDocFiles))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("In the configuration file is missing the path to the root directory - PDX_PathDocFiles.");
        }
        else
        {
            if (!Directory.Exists(pdxPathDocFiles))
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Directory not found");
            }
            else
            {
                try
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("rootPath: " + pdxPathDocFiles);
                    PayDox_EPD19_T20_RGMEntities db = new PayDox_EPD19_T20_RGMEntities();
                    System.IO.DirectoryInfo rootDir = new DirectoryInfo(pdxPathDocFiles);
                    db.FileDBRecord.RemoveRange(db.FileDBRecord);

                    WalkDirectoryTree(rootDir, rootDir.ToString(), db);
                    db.SaveChanges();
                }
                catch (Exception)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Failed to connect to the database");
                }
                Console.WriteLine("All ok");
            }
        }
        Console.WriteLine("Bye, Good Day.");
    }
    static void WalkDirectoryTree(System.IO.DirectoryInfo root, string rootDir, PayDox_EPD19_T20_RGMEntities db)
    {
        System.IO.FileInfo[] files = null;
        System.IO.DirectoryInfo[] subDirs = null;
        try
        {
            files = root.GetFiles("*.*");
        }

        catch (UnauthorizedAccessException e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
        }

        catch (System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
        }

        if (files != null)
        {
            foreach (System.IO.FileInfo fi in files)
            {
                db.FileDBRecord.Add(new FileDBRecord { FileName = fi.FullName.Replace(rootDir, ""), FileSize = fi.Length });
            }

            subDirs = root.GetDirectories();

            foreach (System.IO.DirectoryInfo dirInfo in subDirs)
            {
                WalkDirectoryTree(dirInfo, rootDir, db);
            }
        }
        db.SaveChanges();
    }
```

When I try another way, it throw-out with exception stack overflow exception.

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string pdxPathDocFiles = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["PDX_PathDocFiles"] as string;
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(pdxPathDocFiles))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("In the configuration file is missing the path to the root directory - PDX_PathDocFiles.");
        }
        else
        {
            if (!Directory.Exists(pdxPathDocFiles))
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Directory not found");
            }
            else
            {
                try
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("rootPath: " + pdxPathDocFiles);
                    PayDox_EPD19_T20_RGMEntities db = new PayDox_EPD19_T20_RGMEntities();
                    db.FileDBRecord.RemoveRange(db.FileDBRecord);
                    db.SaveChanges();
                    Console.WriteLine("Remove data from table");

                    System.IO.FileInfo[] files = null;
                    System.IO.DirectoryInfo rootDir2 = new DirectoryInfo(pdxPathDocFiles);
                    try
                    {
                        files = rootDir2.GetFiles("*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories);
                        Console.WriteLine("Reed {0} fileName", files.Length);
                    }
                    catch (UnauthorizedAccessException ex)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("You do not have permission to access one or more folders in this directory tree.");
                        Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
                        return;
                    }

                    db.FileDBRecord.AddRange(files.Select(x => new FileDBRecord { FileName = x.FullName.Replace(pdxPathDocFiles, ""), FileSize = x.Length }));
                    db.SaveChanges();
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
                }
                Console.WriteLine("All ok");
            }
        }
        Console.WriteLine("Bye, Good Day.");
    }
```

How make program faster, maybe add multithreading?

Comment: Multi-threading won't help. You're doing a lot of I/O operations and your hard drive can only answer one request per time, no matter how many threads try to ask for files (ok, the os may cache something). The bottle-neck is not the thread it's the I/O operation and that cannot be well parallelized.

Comment: @RenéVogt MultiThreading can help if you had an eye on the used resources. Writing to a remote db did not consume I/O on the local HDD, so you can parallize it. TPL DataFlow can help to design such process

Comment: @SirRufo I agree of course that writing to the DB could itself be parallelized and be done parallel to reading from disk, too. But I still guess that the bottle neck is the hdd part, and creating a lot of threads to read from the same hdd won't help.

Comment: @Sir Rufo And How I mast use TPL? Can you write example, please?

Comment: TPL DataFlow is well documented at https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/hh228603(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Before any optimization you should measure how long it takes to get all the files and how long it takes to write all entries to the database. The lowest time of both is the best result you will ever get. If writing to the database will take 3.5 days it is maybe not worth to optimize at all ;o)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For starters, your code isn't async. Break this out into a separate class and make the methods async. This allows the thread to be used while waiting for an IO operation. Anytime your calling the Database or File system use async equivalent methods.

The second thing I would do is try to make is so each transaction is atomic. If you doing something x amount of times, write the program in such a way that each x time can be done is isolation. Once that is done you can run these is parallel by creating a new Task (Task.Run).

Once those 2 are done and the task is still taking a while, look into [TPL Dataflow](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh228603(v=vs.110).aspx). That can buffer requests for you to optimize your process.

Answer (score 0):

I improved first example from msdn, by adding there TPL library.
Now it working 4 hour, not 4 days.

```html
static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string pdxPathDocFiles = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["PDX_PathDocFiles"] as string;
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(pdxPathDocFiles))
            {
                Console.WriteLine("In the configuration file is missing the path to the root directory - PDX_PathDocFiles.");
            }
            else
            {
                if (!Directory.Exists(pdxPathDocFiles))
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Directory not found");
                }
                else
                {
                    try
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("rootPath: " + pdxPathDocFiles);
                        PayDox_EPD19_T20_RGMEntities db = new PayDox_EPD19_T20_RGMEntities();
                        System.IO.DirectoryInfo rootDir = new DirectoryInfo(pdxPathDocFiles);
                        db.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("TRUNCATE TABLE [FileDBRecord]");
                        db.SaveChanges();
                        db.Dispose();
                        Console.WriteLine("Remove data from table");

                        WalkDirectoryTree(rootDir, rootDir.ToString());
                        Console.WriteLine("All ok");
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
                    }
                }
            }
            Console.WriteLine("Bye, Good Day.");
            Console.WriteLine("Processing complete. Press any key to exit.");
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
        static void WalkDirectoryTree(System.IO.DirectoryInfo root, string rootDir)
        {
            //Console.WriteLine("Go to folder: "+  root.FullName.Replace(rootDir, ""));
            System.IO.FileInfo[] files = null;
            System.IO.DirectoryInfo[] subDirs = null;
            try
            {
                files = root.GetFiles("*.*");
            }

            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
            }

            if (files != null)
            {
                PayDox_EPD19_T20_RGMEntities db = new PayDox_EPD19_T20_RGMEntities();
                foreach (var currentElement in files)
                {
                    db.FileDBRecord.Add(new FileDBRecord { FileName = currentElement.FullName.Replace(rootDir, ""), FileSize = currentElement.Length });
                }
               
                db.SaveChanges();
                db.Dispose();
                subDirs = root.GetDirectories();


                Parallel.ForEach(subDirs,
                currentElement =>
                {
                    try
                    {
                        WalkDirectoryTree(currentElement, rootDir);
                    }
                    catch (Exception e)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
                    }
                });
            }

        }
    }
```

Answer (score -2):

maybe we can fix your second code.. (untested, but may not throw the exception)
if you test it, let me know if it is faster..

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string pdxPathDocFiles = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["PDX_PathDocFiles"] as string;
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(pdxPathDocFiles))
    {
        Console.WriteLine("In the configuration file is missing the path to the root directory - PDX_PathDocFiles.");
    }
    else
    {
        if (!Directory.Exists(pdxPathDocFiles))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Directory not found");
        }
        else
        {
            try
            {
                Console.WriteLine("rootPath: " + pdxPathDocFiles);
                PayDox_EPD19_T20_RGMEntities db = new PayDox_EPD19_T20_RGMEntities();
                db.FileDBRecord.RemoveRange(db.FileDBRecord);
                db.SaveChanges();
                Console.WriteLine("Remove data from table");

                IList<FileDBRecord> files = null;
                System.IO.DirectoryInfo rootDir2 = new DirectoryInfo(pdxPathDocFiles);
                try
                {
                    files = rootDir2.GetFiles("*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories).Select(x => new FileDBRecord { FileName = x.FullName.Replace(pdxPathDocFiles, ""), FileSize = x.Length });
                    Console.WriteLine("Reed {0} fileName", files.Length);
                }
                catch (UnauthorizedAccessException ex)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("You do not have permission to access one or more folders in this directory tree.");
                    Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
                    return;
                }

                files.Foreach(db.FileDBRecord);
                db.SaveChanges();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            }
            Console.WriteLine("All ok");
        }
    }
    Console.WriteLine("Bye, Good Day.");
}
```

Comment: This code throw «stack overflow exception», when makes this command
files = rootDir2.GetFiles("*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories);